# How to increase/decrease the number in $_GET variable link?

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP page that utilizes a $_GET variable, "link", to display a specific image on the page. My PHP page URLs look like "website.com/page.php?link=1"

PHP Code:

```
$link = $_GET['link'];
if($link == 1) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image1.jpg";}
if($link == 2) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image2.jpg";}
if($link == 3) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image3.jpg";}
```

HTML

```
<img src="<?=$linkURL;?>"></img>
```

I want to add 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons on this page, which will go to the next/previous $link URL when clicked.

```
<a class="prevBtn" href="">Previous</a>
<a class="nextBtn" href="">Next/a>
```

What should I put as the href in order to achieve this? Basically, I want it to be "$link -1" for previous and "$link +1" for next.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You practically wrote your answer in the question. Follow your logic through!

Comment: So it's href="<?=$linkURL+1;?> ? Does the semicolon go before or after the +1?

Comment: As you have it in your comment example.

Comment: Doing <a class="prevBtn" href="<?=$linkURL-1;?>">Previous</a> does not produce the correct link. It prints out "website.com/-1" instead of "website.com/page.php?link=-1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your images will always be image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg etc, you can achieve what you're looking for like this:

Note: I used PHP only just so it's easier to follow the logic

```
<?php

//Check $_GET variable exists otherwise set it to a default value = 1

if(isset($_GET['link'])) { 
    $link = $_GET['link'];
} else {
     $link = 1;
}

if($link == 1) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image1.jpg";}
if($link == 2) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image2.jpg";}
if($link == 3) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image3.jpg";}

// Set variables for the previous and next links
$prev = $link-1;
$next = $link+1;

//Display your image    
echo "<img src='".$linkURL."'></img>";

//Only show the previous button if it's NOT the first image
if($prev!=0){
     echo "<a class='prevBtn' href='http://website.com/page.php?link=".$prev."'>Previous</a>";
}

//Only show the next button if it's NOT the last image
if($next<=3){
    echo "<a class='nextBtn' href='http://website.com/page.php?link=".$next."'>Next</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: The images won't be always image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc. The image names vary greatly.

Comment: So I need to keep
`$link = $_GET['link'];`
`if($link == 1) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image1.jpg";}`
`if($link == 2) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image2.jpg";}`
`if($link == 3) { $linkURL = "http://website.com/image3.jpg";}`

Comment: Made a small edit to account for different named images

Comment: It looks good but it is giving me '500 Internal Server Error'.

Comment: it says "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /file-path/page.php on line 45

Comment: Is there an unexpected '{' in this code?
`if(isset($_GET['link']) { 
    $link = $_GET['link'];
} else {
     $link = 1;
}`

Comment: I was missing a bracket on the first if statement. I also edited the if statements on the prev and next buttons. Code is tested and works now

Comment: It's very close to working. The only problem now is that the 'Next' button is only showing on "page.php?link=1" and not on "page.php?link=2", "page.php?link=3", and so on.

Comment: Maybe it should be "if($LINK<3){..." instead of NEXT. I will test.

Comment: Yes ^ The above fixed it. If you want to change it on your answer, I will accept it as correct. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You try can pass the parameters through url as

```
<a class="prevBtn" href="<?php echo $linkURL?>?link=-1">Previous</a>
<a class="nextBtn" href="<?php echo $linkURL?>?link=+1">Next/a>
```

Comment: This is close, but doesn't quite achieve the right effect. In your example, it echos the $linkURL, which is a link to an image. So the URL that shows is "http://website.com/image1.jpg?link=-1" which isn't what we are going for.

Say the current URL is "http://website.com/page.php?link=2" I want the previous button to be "http://website.com/page.php?link=1"

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Do you want Carousel like effect?

Comment: And even if we set it in for loop it will ultimately increase the number of anchor tags too.

Comment: A carousel effect is not needed. I just want it to the next or previous link.

Comment: If the current URL is "website.com/page.php?link=2", I want the next button to link to "website.com/page.php?link=3" and the previous button to link to ""website.com/page.php?link=1"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing this would be to use an array. The advantage of this is you can just add new images to the array and it will still work. You don't have to worry about editing the other if statements around the next button.

```
<?php

//Check $_GET variable exists otherwise set it to a default value = 1

$images = [
"image1.jpg",
"image2.jpg",
"image3.jpg",
];

if(isset($_GET['link']) { 
    $link = $_GET['link'];
} else {
     $link = 0;
}

if(!$images[$link]) {
    $link=0;
}

// Set variables for the previous and next links
$prev = $link-1;
$next = $link+1;

//Display your image    
echo "<img src='http://website.com/".$images[$link]."'></img>";

//Only show the previous button if it's NOT the first image
if($prev<0){
     echo "<a class='prevBtn' href='http://website.com/page.php?link=".$prev."'>Previous</a>";
}

//Only show the next button if it's NOT the last image
if($next!=count($images)){
    echo "<a class='nextBtn' href='http://website.com/page.php?link=".$next."'>Next</a>";
}
?>
```